# Problem with WCF

Tags: wcf

Hey, here is my class code

```
    namespace WcfServicepractice
   {
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class WebDataService1 : IMyclass
    {
        public int add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        public int multi(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Interface code,

```
namespace WcfServicepractice
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface  IMyclass
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int add(int a,int b);

        [OperationContract]
        int multi(int a, int b);
    }


}
```

this is my web.config for my service

```
 <behavior name="WcfServicepractice.WebDataService1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
 </behavior>

<service name="WcfServicepractice.WebDataService1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfServicepractice.WebDataService1Behavior" >
   <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServicepractice.IMyclass" >
     <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
     </identity>
   </endpoint>
   <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

When i run the code i get this error

> The webpage cannot be found

Can someone help ?

Thanks..

Comment: Do you have a corresponding `.svc` file?

Comment: Yes i do have a .svc file, the address I'm browsing to is localhost:1049/WebDataService1.svc

Comment: You're using wsHttpBinding - you won't be able to just *browse* to your service.... you need to run a SOAP client - e.g. your own code, of the WCF Test Client - in order to talk to your service (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From your error I assume you're trying to host the service in IIS (in this case probably using the Cassini server)

Do you have a svc file in your project?
What address are you browsing to?

You should be browsing to something like: http://localhost:someport/service.svc

Comment: Yes i do have a .svc file, the address I'm browsing to is http://localhost:1049/WebDataService1.svc